# Is there a way to retrieve the right-most non-empty cell in a spreadsheet? Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

This one is a bit of a long shot, but is there a way to determine which cell in a table is the right-most cell that isn't blank? I have a table that has empty cells on purpose; there's nothing to be recorded. I want to retrieve the right-most cell that still has data. For example:

**Table 1**

| Primary Key | Status 1 | Status 2 | Status 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | Alpha | Beta | Charlie |
| Bob | Delta |  |  |
| Carol | Echo | Foxtrot |  |
| Eve | Golf | Hotel |  |
| Frank | India | Juliet | Kilo |

Ideally, the formula would return a list of all the cells it retrieves. In my particular implementation, I don't think it matters what order the returned list is in; this example is more to demonstrate what the table looks like rather than what my data is. It also doesn't matter if it's "attached" to the primary key; the ideal return would be a list that looks like "Charlie, Delta, Foxtrot, Hotel, Kilo." I will be using this generated list for a FILTER function later on, if that changes anything.

Theoretically, it *might* be possible for me to re-work the data? However, since there are 1000+ entries, I'd rather not have to go through by hand, especially since I will be using this data structure for other formulas later.

EDIT: The values are non-consecutive and are strings; I misrepresented the data in the original example. My apologies.

Comment: Are all the values consecutive?, are they always in ascending order?

Comment: No, the values are non-consecutive. I'll clarify that in the post.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=IFNA(BYROW(A2:E; LAMBDA(x; LOOKUP(1; INDEX(1/(x<>"")); x))))
```

[image]

Comment: Even works for blank rows, neat.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your table is from `column A` to `column H` (idk how many colums you need).

You can put in column I this formula (or some column in different sheet):

```
=INDEX(A2:H2 , ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(COLUMN(A2:H2)*(--(A2:H2<>"")))))
```

Just cover full `colomn I` and it will put last value for `row 2` in `I2`, for `row 3` in `I3` etc.

I cant think of any formula that will join al of that in one cell, but if I do ull update the answer.

Hope this helps.

(Formula is done in US Locale. If you are not in US you can change it in `File>Setings>Locale`.)